# « En vacances » / « Aux vacances »

Tags: prépositions, vacances

Can someone please explain me when we have to use « en vacances » (Partir en vacances pour trois semaines..) or « aux vacances » (partir aux vacances de Noël).

I think you normally use « en vacances » when you speak about holidays in general, but when you specifically mention a special type of holidays (vacances d'avril, vacances de Pâques) you use « aux ». Is this correct?

Pourriez-vous m'en dire un peu plus à ce sujet ?

Comment: D'où tenez vous "partir aux vacances" ? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=partir+en+vacances%2Cpartir+aux+vacances&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartir%20en%20vacances%3B%2Cc0 -- On part **en** vacances **à** Noël, **à** Pâques (ou à la Trinité :)

Comment: @cl-r On peut le voir par exemple dans "Je rentre chez mes parents aux vacances de Noël".

Comment: @ThomasFrancois -- Rentrer ***à** la maison*, un lieu ; rentrer [***durant/pendant les | au début/à la fin des**] vacances*, une période. Mélanger les deux n'appartient pas au langage soutenu, il vaut mieux en déconseiller l'usage.

Comment: @cl-r [nous partirons aux vacances de printemps](http://www.routard.com/forum_message/3746882/petite_escale_entre_bastia_et_porto_vecchio_en_avril_2015.htm) - [je partirai aux vacances de Noël](http://www.mamanpourlavie.com/forum/sujet/les-testeuses-de-mai-2010-qui-espa-rent-des-petits-bourgeons/page/77) etc. etc.

Comment: @Laure -- On peut le dire, l'écrire dans une discussion Internet, tout le monde comprendra de quoi il s'agit. Est-ce pour autant une formulation correcte comme *le demande la question* ?  Elle n'est pas encore entrée à l'Académie à ma connaissance (Cf Ngram) mais l'usage l'y fera peut-être acceptée  bientôt.

Comment: @cl-r 1-un ngram ne reflète que l'expression exacte (qui ne parle qu'avec l’infinitif ?) ; 2- un ngram ne fait des recherches que dans des livres publiés au plus tard au début du 21e s. 3- Aucun rapport entre le fait d'être dans un livre (→(Cf Ngram)) et une quelconque « entrée à l'Académie » (Française ?). 4- Et de toutes façon L'Académie Française n'est pas le reflet de la langue de la majorité des français. La préposition s'emploie, entre autres pour marquer le temps, et c'est ainsi qu'elle et utilisé dans *je pars à 8 heures, je partirai à la nuit, je suis parti aux vacances d'été,* etc...

Comment: Pour ajouter à la discussion, et on le souhaite avoir le plaisir de vous lire en réponse, _Jean Mistler_ (Ac. F14, 1966) : « _À Pâques, à Pentecôte, aux grandes vacances, nous revenions toujours à Sorèze._ » (_Bout du monde_).

Comment: @SurvenantLazurite --  Dans votre exemple, *les grandes vacances* sont une période, comme Noël, Pâques... ce ne sont pas les congés durant lesquels vous êtes *en vacances* ....

Comment: @Laure (pour répondre aux deux commentaires :) --  ... et la confusion possible entre *vacances = période de repos* et *vacances = droit aux congés* ; *partir aux congés de Noël* (cela ressemble à un avis de décès) est sûrement possible, mais je me demande si cela est correct (dans un langage soutenu, comme le demande LiseP)

Comment: Il y a aussi _pour les vacances_, qui sera également compris.

Answer (score 7):

Il y a une différence d'emploi et de sens entre *en vacances* et *aux vacances*.

Sans autre précision de temps ou de lieu l'expression est « partir en vacances ».

***En vacances*** sert à exprimer la façon / la raison dont on s'en va.

> Je ne pars pas en vacances, je me déplace pour mon travail.

Dans ***aux vacances***, la préposition *à* (à+les = aux) sert à introduire un complément de temps.

> Je partirai aux vacances de printemps.

C'est synonyme de « Je partirai pendant les vacances de printemps. »

Comparons :

- > Je vais partir aux vacances d'été.

  veut dire sans ambiguïté que je partirai au moment des vacances d'été mais je ne dis rien sur la façon dont je vais passer mes vacances et j'ai peut-être l'intention d'aller pratiquer des activités qui dans mon environnement habituel ne se pratique qu'en hiver (ski nordique, etc...).
- > Je vais partir en vacances d'été.

  exprime mon intention de pratiquer des activités qui dans mon environnement habituel se font en été (plage, randonnée, etc..). Je veux peut-être dire aussi que je vais partir en été  mais ce n'est pas explicite.

---

*En vacances* and *aux vacances* have indeed specific uses.

Without further details of time and place the phrase is *en vacances*.

***En vacances*** is used to to express the way or the reason we are going.

> Je ne pars pas en vacances, je me déplace pour mon travail.

(I'm not going on holiday, I'm going for my work.)

> Je partirai aux vacances de printemps.

Means I'll be going during the spring holiday. Preposition *à* introduces a time phrase.

Let's compare :

- > Je vais partir aux vacances d'été.

  Means I intend to go on holiday during the summer, it does not say what sort of activities I intend to have, I might very well go skiing in the mountains, which in my part of the world is a winter practice.
- > Je vais partir en vacances d'été.

  Means I intend to spend my holiday time practising activities that are summer activities in my usual environment. It might very well be winter time where I live and I'm going to have a holiday on a sunny beach in Australia.

Comment: awesome answer ! For me (but maybe it's just me), using "Je vais partir en vacances d'été" often implies that I will stay in vacation longer than if I say "Je vais partir aux vacances d'été".

Comment: You forgot to mention another possibility, that can replace "aux" pretty much everytime, I'm talking of course about "pendant les". Also, you can make use of both those terms in a sentence that'll look like this: "Je vais partir en vacances aux/pendant les vacances d'été." Kinda redundant, but perfectly acceptable to tell that you are going on vacation during a specific holiday, given that in French, holiday and vacation are the same word. One more thing, you can also use in different contexts: "prendre des vacances", "être en vacances."

Comment: @MorganFR  Yes, Your sentence is a good example of what I was explaining!  I did mention *pendant* as a synonym of *aux*.

Comment: +1 mais *la façon / la raison dont on s'en va* et son pendant *the reason we are going* « sonnent gauche… »

Answer (score 1):

This is roughly correct. "Partir en vacances" is an idiom in which vacances cannot really be bound to another qualifier. You cannot say "partir aux vacances" either. But you can say "partir en vacances à Noël", "partir en vacances à Pâques", "partir en vacances aux États-Unis", etc. when the qualifier applies to partir.