# « Bon vacances » ou « bonnes vacances » ?

Tags: accord, genre

J'ai pensé qu'on dit : *« je vous souhaite de bonnes vacances »*, et donc *« Bonnes vacances »*, mais l’œil qui voit tout m'a donné :

http://www.answers.com/Q/Should_you_write_bonnes_vacances_or_bon_vacances

qui conseille : « Bon vacances. »

Un francophone peut-il m'assister ?

Comment: Answers.com is kind of a joke, or clickbait, nowadays. No way to ask new questions, no way to correct questions or replies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Je suis française et on dit *« Bonnes vacances »* ; *« vacances »* étant un nom féminin pluriel comme noté dans le dictionnaire. Ainsi, ce qui est noté dans le site fourni est faux, voir [Vacances](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/vacances)

In English (I tried my best)

> I'm French and here we say "Bonnes vacances" as "vacances" is a plural feminine word as the dictionary says. In this way, what's written in the linked website is false, see [Vacances](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/vacances)

PS : We say "Joyeux Noël" as "Noël" is a masculine word.

Comment: C'est le participe passé de *fournir* que tu utilses là. ;-)

Comment: Oui, je trouve que "le site lié" n'est pas une belle formulation française, ainsi que "the provided website" est beaucoup moins naturel que "the linked website"

Answer (score 3):

Vacances c'est bien féminin pluriel. On peut le vérifier facilement avec un dictionnaire. Voici wiki par exemple :

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vacance

Il faut dire *bonnes vacances*.

> Je vous souhaite (de passer) de bonnes vacances

**Attention aux sens pour vacance :**

> singulier : État de ce qui est vacant.
>
> pluriel : Période plus ou moins longue pendant laquelle une personne
> cesse toute activité professionnelle pour se reposer, se détendre.
>
> singular: State of what is vacant.
>
> plural: The length of time during which a person stops any professional activity to rest, relax.

Voir ici :

http://amourdelalanguefrancaise.blogspirit.com/archive/2014/07/02/vacance-vacances-vacations-ferie-3010186.html

ou ici :

https://www.lexilogos.com/vacances_etymologie.htm

Une autre question sur FSE :

[« En vacances » / « Aux vacances »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19472/en-vacances-aux-vacances)

Comment: Cette réponse, bien que son contenu soit parfaitement correct, ne correspond pas à la question de l'OP. L'ajout du genre y pallierait !